# how to replace Unicode Hex Character Code

Tags: python, unicode, hex

```
my_string = "smart watch Xiaomi &#x2F; Smart watches for women, men, children"
```

How can I get the character "/".

i do this: `my_string.replace("&#x2F;", "/")`
But I don't want to use this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`html` — HyperText Markup Language support](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/html.html)

> `html.unescape(s)`
>
> Convert all named and numeric character references (e.g. `&gt;`,
> `&#62;`, `&#x3e;`) in the string s to the corresponding Unicode
> characters. This function uses the rules defined by the HTML 5
> standard for both valid and invalid character references, and [the
> list of HTML 5 named character references](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/html.entities.html#html.entities.html5).
>
> *New in version 3.4.*

```
my_string = "smart watch Xiaomi &#x2F; Smart watches for women, men, children"
import html
html.unescape(my_string)
# 'smart watch Xiaomi / Smart watches for women, men, children'
```